# Error when trying to add a custom font "The "path" argument must be of type string"

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add a custom font to my react native project, I already put the Bungee.ttf on the
assets/fonts foulder and edit the react-native-config.js file:

```
 project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'], // stays the same
};
```

but after `npx react-native link` this error occurs on console:

```
error The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined.
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)
    at Object.basename (node:path:752:5)
    at \node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\link\linkAll.js:62:78
```

npm info react-scripts version: 4.0.3
node version: v16.10.0

How to fix this??

Answer (score 1):

Add the following file in the main folder (under index.js) then try react-native link

file name: react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
project: {
  ios: {},
  android: {}, // grouped into "project"
},
assets: ["./assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
```

};

Comment: I forgot to say that already did this